# Drawing a timeline from div to div with canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I have the following div markup

```
<div data-x="-1000" data-y="-1500">
// content
</div>
<div data-x="0" data-y="-1500">
// content
</div>
```

And I have many of this divs with different data-x and data-y value depending on their position.

What I want to achieve here is to draw something like a timeline between the divs so div1 line to div2 line to div 3 etc,,

I want this to be done automatically So I am trying to make a loop for it but my javascript/jquery knowledge is not that good. Could someone point me in the good direction?

what I have now is

```
    function drawTimeline() {

  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
   var canvas = document.getElementById('timeline');

  // Make sure we don't execute when canvas isn't supported
  if (canvas.getContext){

    // use getContext to use the canvas for drawing
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var prevCoord = {};

    for (var i = -1; div = divs[++i]; ) {
      if (div.dataset.x && div.dataset.y) {
        var x = parseInt(div.dataset.x);
        var y = parseInt(div.dataset.y);
        if ({} !== prevCoord) {

          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineWidth="5";
          ctx.strokeStyle="purple"; // Purple path
          ctx.moveTo(prevCoord.x, prevCoord.y);
          ctx.lineTo(x, y);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.stroke()
        }

          prevCoord.x = x;
          prevCoord.y = y;
      }
    }

  } else {
    alert('You need Safari or Firefox 1.5+ to see this.');
  }

}
```

unfortunately the line is not correct its like a linear line and thats it.. can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Could you better explain the problem? What do you mean by a `linear line`? Your example only has 2 data-points (both of which have positions that are off-canvas) and thus draws an invisible straight-line segment from <-1000,-1500> to <0, -1500> - a vertical line 1000 pixels long. Do you wish to scale the lines, such that an unknown number of segments of unknown length will always fit in a drawing-area of a known and pre-determined size?

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but your problem is that canvas does not draw at negative coordinates.

Therefore, you must map all your data-x and data-y into positive coordinates.

Here's a function that maps your negative values into positive values:

```
function mapRange(value, sourceLow, sourceHigh, mappedLow, mappedHigh) {
    return mappedLow + (mappedHigh - mappedLow) * (value - sourceLow) / (sourceHigh - sourceLow);
}
```

So in your example to map a data-x value of -300 into an onscreen range of 0-1000 can do this:

```
var x = mapRange(-300, -1500,0, 0,1000);  // The mapped x is 466.66.
```

You must reposition your divs to the mapped x,y coordinates which you can do with CSS.

An alternative is to use SVG which creates actual DOM elements that can be positioned at negative coordinates.